# Compiling libuv with libwebsockets

Tags: c, cross-compiling, embedded-linux, libuv, libwebsockets

I am trying to run the "libwebsockets-test-server" that is installed with the LWS library, but it will not run because "lwsts[31616]: libuv support not compiled in".

I have checked that libuv is installed (1.8.0). I also changed the setting for LIBUV in cmake and recompiled the library.

```
LWS_USE_LIBUV = 1
```

**How do I get the project compiled with libuv?**

I am on Ubuntu 16.04, cross-compiling using arm-linux-gcc. I have successfully compiled programs, loaded them to the embedded board (TS-7800), and run the executable, but not yet with LWS. I am relatively new to Linux and cross-compilers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Configuring the cmake using 'cmake -DLWS_WITH_PLUGINS=1', changes the configuration to set LWS_USE_LIBUV equal to 1 and compiles libuv with the make.
Since I was planning to use plugins with LWSWS, this was an appropriate fix for the problem.