# Trouble enabling libuv compilation with libwebsockets

Tags: cmake, libuv, libwebsockets

I want to use libwebsockets in a foreign libuv loop.
My code (inspired from [this simple example](https://libwebsockets.org/git/libwebsockets/tree/minimal-examples/http-server/minimal-http-server-eventlib-foreign)) compiles and links correctly, but at execution, on webpage request, the browser never receives a response from the server.

I build both libwebsockets (v3.1.0) and libuv (v1.25.0) from the sources in my cmake. I use the following command line:

```
cmake -DLWS_WITH_LIBUV=1 .. && make
```

And the cmake ouput mentions the correct value for the option:

```
LWS_WITH_LIBEV = OFF 
LWS_WITH_LIBUV = 1
LWS_WITH_LIBEVENT = OFF
```

Grepping for the option in the build directory gives the following (which looks ok too):

```
CMakeCache.txt:483:LWS_WITH_LIBUV:BOOL=ON
extern/libwebsockets/include/libwebsockets/lws-service.h:185:#ifdef LWS_WITH_LIBUV
extern/libwebsockets/include/libwebsockets/lws-service.h:209:#endif /* LWS_WITH_LIBUV */
extern/libwebsockets/include/libwebsockets.h:157:#ifdef LWS_WITH_LIBUV
extern/libwebsockets/include/libwebsockets.h:165:#endif /* LWS_WITH_LIBUV */
extern/libwebsockets/include/lws_config.h:72:#define LWS_WITH_LIBUV
extern/libwebsockets/lws_config.h:72:#define LWS_WITH_LIBUV
```

However, with the following code (the closest I have from a minimal (not) working example) no message is displayed.

```
#include <uv.h>

int main()
{
    #ifdef LWS_WITH_LIBUV
    std::cout<<"With libuv"<<std::endl;
    #endif
}
```

I've looked [here](https://libwebsockets.org/pipermail/libwebsockets/2017-April/003352.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46436610/compiling-libuv-with-libwebsockets) and I do not know what to do next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I had libwebsockets installed on my system and was linking against this system library, *not* compiled with libuv support.